# PHP - Connect to MS SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, database

I'm trying to connect to a Windows MS Sql Server database using PHPon Linux and I know I have the hostname, port, userid and password correct. I verified this with some client software to make sure I could get to the database.   So I'm sure it's just either the right driver, method, or a syntax issue.  Maybe how the port is used in these.:

This is just example names etc.

```
$server = "myhost.com:1111";
$database = "mydatabasename";
$user = "johndoe";
$pass = "doe1";
$conn = odbc_connect('myhost.com','1111','johndoe','doe1');
```

or

```
$connection_string = "DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};SERVER=$server, 1433;DATABASE=$database";
$conn = odbc_connect( $connection_string, $user, $pass );
```

i did a variation on this using just "SQL Server" as the driver after I found a post about using that instead.

I also tried this:

```
    mysql_connect($server,$user, $pass) or die ("<html><script       language='JavaScript'>alert('Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.'),history.go(-1)</script></html>");
    mysql_select_db($database);
$query = "SELECT * FROM USER_TABLE ";
```

Here some information on the server and database:
Windows Server Standard 2007
MS SQL Server 2008 Standard Edition
Using SQL Server Authentication

I'd prefer the odbc_connect if possible. We use it to connect to another database on an i-Series and that works fine.  But we didn't have to use port either on those.

Thanks
Michael

Comment: I believe you have to specify the port as a separate argument in the string like `...;SERVER=$server, Port=1111;DATABASE=$database;...`

Comment: Thanks Jacob. I'll have to wait until monday at work to check it.  But that makes sense.

Comment: Jacob.  That didn't work.  I went back with that and changed the driver to see if that helped or not but it didn't.

Comment: I got to digging on the Linux box and it only has a driver for AS400 so that explains why that works.  But there is no driver for connecting to MS SQL Server.   So now I have to find a driver first.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server maybe this will help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an up-to-date doc on setting up SQL Server/Drivers on Ubuntu for PHP development.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/php/ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install unixodbc unixodbc-dev  ( I already had this so didn't need to do this one.)
sudo apt-get install tdsodbc freetds freetds-bin php5-odbc
```

The rest is pretty much here:
    http://help.interfaceware.com/kb/904

On my virtual machine of course my driver was located at /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so

my obdbcinst.ini

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = FreeTDS drvier
Driver = /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/i836-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
FileUsage = 1
Usagecount = 1

[AS400]
Driver = /usr/lib/libcwbodbc.so
System = mydatabaseserver.com
Setup = 
FileUsage = 1
Usagecount = 1
```